# PHP readfile() download exact copy of the original file

Tags: php

The title might be confusing but I'll try to explain here.

I have a sample of file. This file is a simple .xml file but with .ciff extension and a specific encoding (the encoding used is UCS2-LE BOM).

The contents in the TEST001.ciff are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
```

that's all.

Now I'm trying to download this file from a browser (not showing the content but actually download it in the downloads folder) and this is the code I'm using so far in my download.php file:

```
<?php
require_once('../../../private/initialize.php');
require_login();

// Redirect if the logged in user is not with admin level
if($session->level == 'user') {
    redirect_to(url_for('/index.php'));
}

include(SHARED_PATH . '/staff_header.php');

if (!empty(h($_GET['filename']))) {

    // We have filename request, lets try download it
    if (file_exists('Files/' . h($_GET['filename']))) { 

        // We have the file on the server so we can download it
        header("Pragma: public");
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename('Files/' . h($_GET['filename'])).'"');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize('Files/' . h($_GET['filename'])));
        readfile('Files/' . h($_GET['filename']));
        exit;

    } else {
        // The file was not found on the server
        $session->message('The requested file was not found on the server.', false);
        redirect_to(url_for('staff/ciff/index.php'));
    }
} else {
    // The file request was invalid
    $session->message('Invalid file request.', false);
    redirect_to(url_for('staff/ciff/index.php'));
}

include(SHARED_PATH . '/staff_footer.php'); 
?>
```

So far so good, when i click on the download hyperlink a file TEST001.ciff is downloaded into my downloads folder BUT when I open the downloaded file i can see this content:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>NESI Ticketing - Admin Area</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/nesiticket/public/stylesheets/staff.css" />
</head>

<body>
<header>
  <h1>NESI Ticketing User Area</h1>
</header>

<navigation>
  <ul>
            <li>Hello,  FirstName LastName</li><br />
    <li><a href="/nesiticket/public/index.php">Home Page</a></li>
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
    <li><a href="/nesiticket/public/staff/index.php">Main Menu</a></li>
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
    <li><a href="/nesiticket/public/staff/logout.php">Logout</a></li>
          </ul>
</navigation>

ÿþ< ? x m l   v e r s i o n = " 1 . 0 "   e n c o d i n g = " U T F - 1 6 " ? >
```

The part at the bottom of the code above looks like this in Notepad++
[image]

Is it possible that I can download an exact copy of the original file? Where have i gone wrong in my code?

Comment: what the function h does ?

Comment: just html characters escaping I'm using "h" as a shortcut -- function h($string="") {
  return htmlspecialchars($string);
}

Comment: And where does that HTML come from? Is that from your site? Or random HTML?

Comment: What is in `include(SHARED_PATH . '/staff_header.php');`?

Comment: That HTML is how download.php looks like, the includes at the top and bottom are just the header and the footer of the site. Maybe i should remove them?

Comment: Weeeeeelll, if you don't want the markup to appear in the downloaded file, you should not include it in case you perform a download ;)

Comment: :O - You're right, I've removed the includes and the file came out as the original. I did not have idea that readfile() does that. My thought was that readfile() reads the file that you pass in as parameter not the actual php file. Could you please post it as answer so I can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is most certainly the inclusion of PHP files that contain HTML.
If the PHP parser encounters anything else outside of a `<?php ?>` tag, which will get echoed as a string to whatever client accepting it (your browser, as a file).

If such inclusion happens around your actual download logic, as in your case with staff_header.php, which contains the HTML seen in your output right before the actual file content, you, of course, end up with a file containing both, the HTML and the file contents and probably even in the wrong encoding.

The possible solutions vary and since you are already working on a low level of PHP with including files and such, it would probably suffice if you moved the download logic right before including your staff_header.php.

As the download code exits, the header won't ever be included if your download happens, but be aware that generally, mixing up logic like this is rather unclean.

I'd recommend to keep this kind of logic seperated and managed on higher order, even if it's just another PHP file containing an if-clause that decides whether the download or the HTML logic should be executend.

Answer (score 0):

This will read the file and send it to the browser as download.

Here the php code.

```
$filename = 'Files/' . h($_GET['filename'];

if(file_exists($filename)){

    //Get file type and set it as Content Type
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    header('Content-Type: ' . finfo_file($finfo, $filename));
    finfo_close($finfo);

    //Use Content-Disposition: attachment to specify the filename
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($filename));

    //No cache
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');

    //Define file size
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));

    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($filename);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Please explain the difference to the already used code - how should yours be integrated?

Comment: I've copied this one and gave me HTTP ERROR 500 code

Comment: @nico ob_clean(); and flush(); to eliminate possible characters that generate an error.

Comment: Please don't simply add new comments - **explain** what you've changed directly in your answer. Keep in mind that others should be able to learn from your answer!

Comment: I got rid of the includes before and after the readfile(). I had no idea that readfile actually loads the file into the doanload.php itself and then sends it to the browser.